# crop visible part of image with dynamically width and height

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a div with overflow:hidden and an image inside that div.Also I have some buttons for zoom in zoom out and for moving the image to all directions via change of margin.How do I crop only the visible part of the image and save it ? Is it possible to do it with only javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can't save an image with javascript. You should do it with PHP.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php

You can do it in combination with Jcrop.

Comment: I see but when the image is zoomed in or zoomed out what image will the php take the normal image or the zoomed?